# conexao http com c++ e curl ou qualquer outra biblioteca

Tags: c++, qt

Estou precisando de fazer requisição url https e http.
Encontrei várias bibliotecas, algumas fáceis, outras nem tanto, mas a única que consegui instalar foi a curl.
Já peguei vários exemplos, o problema é que nos exemplos estão usando linguagem estruturada, e estou implementando isso no qtcreator que usa orientação a objetos. Eu peguei o codigo no seguinte site:
https://gist.github.com/alghanmi/c5d7b761b2c9ab199157

O codigo ficou assim
form1.h

```
#ifndef FORM1_H
#define FORM1_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace std;

namespace Ui {
    class Form1;
}

class Form1 : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT

        public:
            explicit Form1(QWidget *parent = 0);
            string readBuffer;
            CURL *curl;
            CURLcode res;
            size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
            {
                ((string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
                return size * nmemb;
            }

            ~Form1();



        private slots:
            void on_btnLogin_clicked();

        private:
            Ui::Form1 *ui;
        };

        #endif // FORM1_H
```

form1.cpp

```
#include "form1.h"
#include "ui_form1.h"
#include <QWebView>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Form1::Form1(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form1)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);
        this->curl = curl_easy_init();
    }

Form1::~Form1()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Form1::on_btnLogin_clicked()
{
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
}
```

O erro é o seguinte

```
form1.cpp:35: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)
     curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);`
```

Comment: O que `curl_easy_setopt` espera receber como argumento? Parece que não reconheceu que `WriteCallBack` como função, mas como método (_member function_? Foi isso que interpretei, método, de função membro)

Comment: O Qt-5 possui bibliotecas capazes de fazer uma requisição HTTP, olha só: https://karanbalkar.com/2014/02/sending-a-http-request-using-qt-5-framework/

Comment: Lacobus, já li um pouco os codigos sobre ele, mas olha só, eu sou iniciante em c++ e qt5, programava em python2.7 + qt4, e pra mim essa biblioteca ainda é muito complexa pra usar

Comment: Encontrei essa biblioteca aqui https://github.com/whoshuu/cpr
Ela parece ser baseada no curl + python request, e é bem parecida com o que estou acostumada a usar, mas não sei como proceder para instalar ela, seria muito bom poder usar ela

Answer (score 1):

O erro está ocorrendo pois o terceiro argumento (`WriteCallback`) passado na chamada de `curl_easy_setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION)` se trata de um método de classe e não um ponteiro para uma função.

Uma maneira de resolver isso seria tornando o método de `WriteCallback` estático, o que faz ele se comportar como uma função:

```
static size_t WriteCallback( void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp )
{
    ((string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}
```

E alterar a chamada de `curl_easy_setopt(CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION)` para:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Form1::WriteCallback );
```

Comment: agora deu os seguintes erros:
form1.cpp:15: error: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
form1.cpp:26: error: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
e varios erros nas linhas com esse comando curl_easy_setopt